# IndexError: list index out of range 12

Tags: python

```
import sys

print("Hi, " + sys.argv[1] + ".")
print('How Are You?')
```

The error I get is

```
C:\Users\AUDUSER\Desktop\Python\Project1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/AUDUSER/Desktop/Python/Project2/userargument.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AUDUSER/Desktop/Python/Project2/userargument.py", line 3, in <module>
    print("Hi, " + sys.argv[1] + ".")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: And how did you call the script?

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you call the script like: `python yourscript.py SomeName` it should work

Comment: wouldn't `SomeName` correspond to `sys.argv[0]`

Comment: @Lucas no, sys.argv[0] is the file name always, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Answer (score 0):

[sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) represents a list which contain all the inputs provided to the python script in a list, and the first element of that list.

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the python script itself. In your case, since you are not providing an argument to your list, your list is of size 1, hence it throws `list index out of range`

To humor yourself, run this script as `python script.py A B C D`

```
import sys

for item in sys.argv:
    print(item)
```

Your output will be.

```
script.py
A
B
C
D
```

As you can see, the first element in the list was the script name `script.py` followed by other arguments

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv is a list in Python, which contains the command-line arguments passed to the script.

With the len(sys.argv) function you can count the number of arguments.

If you are gonna work with command line arguments, you probably want to 
use sys.argv.

and you should try to put sys.argv[0] instead of sys.argv[1].
take a look at this web page: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv